# map box js; hide and show label

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I've never worked with JavaScript before. I'm trying to create a map where different layers can be hidden per users preference. I came across the helpful example on map box showing the exact code at https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/toggle-layers/.

Now, my problem is, because I have numerous point layers of different magnitudes, I was forced to create several layers and filter them based on the desired attribute so each points appearance reflects that specific magnitude. However, I want all these points to be organized into years, so I grouped the layers. So all my layer names look something like this (2006_mag2,2006_mag8,2010_mag3...).

However, I want the hide/show option to show layers based on years. So I was thinking I could do some sort of operator like we use in sql (i.e. '2006%' or a LIKE operator). Looking at some posts a lot of people use '*' in JavaScript?
So this is what it would look like for each layer individually before:

```
var toggleableLayerIds = [ '2006_mag2', '2010_mag3' ];

for (var i = 0; i < toggleableLayerIds.length; i++) {
    var id = toggleableLayerIds[i];
}
```

and this is my botched attempt at trying to group a number of the layers together:

```
var toggleableLayerIds = [ '2006.*', '2008.*' ];

for (var i = 0; i < toggleableLayerIds.length; i++) {
    var id = toggleableLayerIds[i];
}
```

Any guidance you guys can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use loops with regex to group layerIds by date. Sorry I changed the name of your variables. This will get you an object with layerIds grouped by date.

```js
    var layerIds = [ '2006_mag2', '2010_mag3', '2006_mag8', '2006_mag1', '2008_mag2'];
    var dates = ['2006', '2010'];
    var groupedLayers = {};

    //init your object to have a member for each date
    //this could be done inside the loops below by testing if the array exists before pushing the matching layerId
    for (var i=0; i < dates.length; i++) {
      groupedLayers[dates[i]] = [];
    }
    
    //loop over your layerIds to match with the RegExp
    for (var i=0; i < layerIds .length; i++) {
        for (var j=0; j < dates.length; j++) {
            var searchPattern = new RegExp('^' + dates[j]);
            if (searchPattern.test(layerIds[i])) {
                groupedLayers[dates[j]].push(layerIds[i]);
            }
         }
    }

    console.log(groupedLayers)
```

Please tell me what exact result you need so I could help you more.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The loop makes sense. I'm just hoping to have buttons on the right of the screen with each year. And once someone clicks a button, all the points related to that year will disappear. I don't think it's an understatement to say I have no idea what I'm doing. Here's a jsfiddle, which surprise, surprise, I can't get to work. Any suggestions? https://jsfiddle.net/albinoham/x1qvuzg9/2/#&togetherjs=UfvI3hbGSB

Comment: I have edited the jsFiddle, you may need to provide your mapBox token to make it works [https://jsfiddle.net/x1qvuzg9/4/](https://jsfiddle.net/x1qvuzg9/4/) The map wont appear in the jsfiddle unless you import mapBox ressource files correctly. I suggest to copy/paste the javascript only into your local html files.

Comment: You're an absolute star. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: No problem, thank you to accept my answer as the correct answer